# What should I know before going live with an InnoDB database?

Tags: mysql, innodb

What things should a server- or DB-admin know and do before making a InnoDB database available.

I'm thinking about things like setting correct values for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `innodb_log_file_size`

So what simple things could you forget to configure that would cause the application using the database to work less that optimal?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are some configuration options you should think through before you start.

As long as you're not using myisam at all, you can safely allocate almost all (keep enough to have your OS running comfortably, and enough for your `max_connections`) your memory to `innodb_buffer_pool`. The nice thing about InnoDB is that is handles almost all of the memory stuff by itself, no need to separate stuff like query caches, key buffers etc.

I would recommend that you enable `innodb_file_per_table`, simply because it makes it a lot easier to just browse the file system and see how much space the different tables and databases need. You will still need a generic ibdata file for InnoDB internal use, but you can just define it as `10M:autoextend`. No need to define a lot of different innodb data files with pre-allocated sizes.

`innodb_log_file_size` and `innodb_log_buffer_size` combined must be larger than ten times your biggest blob object if you have a lot of large ones. If you don't (and you shouldn't [[1](http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Storing-blobs-in-database-vs-filesystem),[2](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525)]), there is really no need to bother a lot with it. Check [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/11/21/how-to-calculate-a-good-innodb-log-file-size/) for a detailed report on how to calculate.

And when you've run your MySQL for a while, check your settings with [MySQLTuner](http://wiki.mysqltuner.com/MySQLTuner) or [MySQL Tuning Primer](http://www.day32.com/MySQL/).

For a more detailed report, try [mysqlreport](http://hackmysql.com/mysqlreport), and for live monitoring, check [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/).

Comment: One thing to remember about innodb_file_per_table is that the methods used to recover disk space are different.  With ibdata files you can recover space in the tablespace by deleting off the end of your tables.  With individual table files space is not recovered by deleting, one has to rebuild the table with optimize table to return space to the filesystem.  Optimize locks the table and so can cause downtime in your application.

Answer (score 2):

One slight "surprise" to me was that innodb uses, by default, one file for all databases/tables. As opposed to MyISAM tables that uses a directory per database and files per table/tableindex.

That might matter if you're used to shrink the physical files on a table basis (optimize table xxx)